# Dual and Second Dual Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B={e_1, e_2, e_3 }$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Build the dual and second dual basis of  $\mathbb{R}^3$.

This is a question about finding the base to a vector space which makes a specific dual space basis a dual basis.

I have a dual space $V^∗$ (of a vector space $V$) with an ordered base $B^∗=(y_1,\dots,y_n).$

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly...

Since the space is finite dimensional, a basis for the dual space is $\left\{ y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}\right\} $ with

$$y_{i}\left(e_{j}\right)=\delta_{i,j}\equiv\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }i=j\\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

Since $y_{i}$ is linear, $y_{i}\left(x\right)$ (where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$) is determined by the previous equation by writing $x=c_{1}e_{1}+c_{2}e_{2}+c_{3}e_{3}$ and
$$
y_i\left(x\right)=y_{i}\left(c_{1}e_{1}+c_{2}e_{2}+c_{3}e_{3}\right)=c_{1}y_{i}\left(e_{1}\right)+c_{2}y_{i}\left(e_{2}\right)+c_{3}y_{i}\left(e_{3}\right).
$$

Since the dual space is finite-dimensional too, you can continue in
this way to construct a basis for the second dual. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Finite-dimensional_case.